# modx revo не грузится админка

Tags: modx

Проблема такая: установил на modx Collections создал 1 ресурс коллекции, удалил его, удалил Collections. Удалилось без проблем, но перестала грузиться админка. Просто белый экран. Перепробовал все возможные способы решения этой проблемы чистил кэш везде, менял настройки в кэше compress_css и compress_js на 0. Разные способы попробовал, реакции 0. Что можно предпринять в таком случае? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Смотри логи апача - там наверняка есть ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Если у меня такая проблема с РЕВО, я иду по такому списку:

- Проверяю какой код выдает страница, которая не открывается
- Иду в логи, смотрю на ошибки (`error_log`, `access_log`)
- Обычно там `500` ошибка, или `503`. В обоих случах:

  1. Очищаю `cache` (`/core/cache`) в MODx Revo
  2. Проверяю коннект к БД
  3. Проверяю указание путей в `config` (`/`, `/core/`, `/manager/`)
- Если ошибка отличается от `500` и `503` - пытаемся просто очистить `cache`

В  90% случаев у меня всё работало отлично после этих процедур.

Comment: cache чистил несколько раз. Коннект к БД есть ибо все страницы сайта грузятся отлично, проблемы только с админкой. Пути все верно прописаны, и в принципе всё работало до того момента. Логи увы не доступны просто.

Comment: Нужны логи, иначе просто тычем пальцем в небо...

Answer (score 0):

вообще, чтобы понимать, что происходит, в папке **manager** в файле **index.php** в начале кода впишите

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
```

Так можно будет увидеть ошибки. Тогда и понимать, что происходит, будет гораздо легче.

Только потом не забудьте удалить записи...